# SVG icon animation leaves a pixel gap

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, frontend, pixel

I'm working on SVG animations with CSS and I've noticed that with my line drawing animations, any SVG rect (#clipboard-border and #clipboard-clip-border) stroke always excludes a bit of the top-left corner, which makes it an incomplete rectangle.

I've tried adjusting the stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset measurements within the CSS, as well as adjusting the sizes and pixel coordinated within the SVG code, but neither are the problem it seems. Help?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #CECECE;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
}
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 3% auto;
  padding: 0px 100px;
}
/* --------------------- 
SVG RULES
--------------------- */

/* All grey strokes */

#clipboard-border,
.clipboard-content,
.clipboard-borders,
.mech-pencil-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #4D5152;
  stroke-width: 6;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
/* All things white */

#clipboard-paper-fill,
#mech-pencil-eraser-fill {
  fill: #F3F7F6;
}
/* All things green */

#mech-pencil-point-fill,
#mech-pencil-top-fill {
  fill: #25B686;
}
/* All things blue */

#clipboard-fill {
  fill: #85D0D3;
}
/* All things yellow */

#clipboard-clip-fill,
#mech-pencil-grip {
  fill: #FBFBCE;
}
#clipboard-knob-1,
#clipboard-knob-2,
#clipboard-knob-3,
#mech-pencil-bottom-btn,
#mech-pencil-top-btn {
  stroke-dasharray: 8px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 8px;
  animation: trace .5s ease-out forwards;
}
/* ---------------------
ANIMATION KEYFRAMES 
--------------------- */

@keyframes trace {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes fill-it {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(.9);
  }
}
/* --------------------- 
SVG ANIMATION: INSIGHT & PLANNING ICON 
--------------------- */

#clipboard-clip-border {
  stroke-dasharray: 180px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 180px;
  animation: trace .2s ease-out forwards;
}
#clipboard-clip-fill {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fill-it .2s .2s ease-in-out forwards;
}
#clipboard-border {
  stroke-dasharray: 640px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 640px;
  animation: trace 1.25s ease-in-out forwards;
}
#clipboard-fill,
#mech-pencil-point-fill,
#mech-pencil-top-fill {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fill-it .25s 1.25s ease-in-out forwards;
}
#clipboard-paper-border {
  stroke-dasharray: 400px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 400px;
  animation: trace 1s ease-out forwards;
}
#clipboard-paper-fill,
#mech-pencil-eraser-fill,
#mech-pencil-grip {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fill-it .75s 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
#clipboard-content-line-1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 30px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 30px;
  animation: trace .5s ease-out forwards;
}
#clipboard-content-line-7,
#clipboard-clip-detail {
  stroke-dasharray: 52px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 52px;
  animation: trace .5s ease-out forwards;
}
#clipboard-content-line,
#clipboard-content-line-even,
#mech-pencil-eraser-border {
  stroke-dasharray: 80px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 80px;
  animation: trace .75s ease-out forwards;
}
#mech-pencil-border-left,
#mech-pencil-border-right {
  stroke-dasharray: 115px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 115px;
  animation: trace .75s ease-out forwards;
}
#mech-pencil-point-border {
  stroke-dasharray: 60px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 60px;
  animation: trace .5s ease-out forwards;
}
#mech-pencil-tip,
#mech-pencil-top {
  stroke-dasharray: 10px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 10px;
  animation: trace .4s ease-out forwards;
}
/* --------------------- 
ANIMATION DELAYS
--------------------- */

#clipboard-knob-1,
#clipboard-knob-2 {
  animation-delay: .25s;
}
#clipboard-clip-detail,
#clipboard-content-line,
#clipboard-content-line-7,
#clipboard-knob-2 {
  animation-delay: .5s;
}
#mech-pencil-bottom-btn,
#mech-pencil-top-btn {
  animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- INSIGHT & PLANNING ICON -->

  <svg id="insight-planning" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <g class="clipboard">
      <rect id="clipboard-fill" x="15.015" y="11.44" width="132" height="182" />
      <rect id="clipboard-paper-fill" x="30.753" y="11.44" width="100" height="151" />
      <g class="clipboard-content">
        <line id="clipboard-content-line-even" x1="46.491" y1="68.096" x2="115.738" y2="68.096" />
        <line id="clipboard-content-line" x1="46.491" y1="80.687" x2="115.738" y2="80.687" />
        <line id="clipboard-content-line-even" x1="46.491" y1="93.277" x2="115.738" y2="93.277" />
        <line id="clipboard-content-line" x1="46.491" y1="105.867" x2="115.738" y2="105.867" />
        <line id="clipboard-content-line-even" x1="46.491" y1="118.458" x2="115.738" y2="118.458" />
        <line id="clipboard-content-line-7" x1="46.491" y1="131.048" x2="96.852" y2="131.048" />
        <line id="clipboard-content-line-1" x1="115.738" y1="49.211" x2="90.557" y2="49.211" />
      </g>
      <rect id="clipboard-border" x="15.015" y="11.44" width="132" height="182" />
    </g>
    <g class="mech-pencil-fills">
      <rect id="mech-pencil-grip" x="166.099" y="96.425" width="18" height="47" />
      <rect id="mech-pencil-top-fill" x="166.099" y="30.325" width="18" height="66" />
      <rect id="mech-pencil-eraser-fill" x="166.099" y="11.44" width="18" height="18" />
      <polygon id="mech-pencil-point-fill" points="184.985,143.639 184.985,159.376 175.542,168.819 166.099,159.376 166.099,143.639" />
    </g>
    <g class="mech-pencil-borders">
      <line id="mech-pencil-border-left" x1="166.099" y1="143.639" x2="166.099" y2="30.325" />
      <line id="mech-pencil-border-right" x1="184.985" y1="30.325" x2="184.985" y2="145" />
      <rect id="mech-pencil-eraser-border" x="166.099" y="11.44" width="18" height="18" />
      <polygon id="mech-pencil-point-border" points="184.985,143.639 184.985,159.376 175.542,168.819 166.099,159.376 166.099,143.639" />
      <line id="mech-pencil-top" x1="175.542" y1="11.44" x2="175.542" y2="1.997" />
      <line id="mech-pencil-tip" x1="175.542" y1="168.819" x2="175.542" y2="175.114" />
      <line id="mech-pencil-bottom-btn" x1="175.542" y1="127.901" x2="175.542" y2="121.605" />
      <line id="mech-pencil-top-btn" x1="175.542" y1="115.31" x2="175.542" y2="109.015" />
    </g>
    <g class="clipboard-clip">
      <rect id="clipboard-clip-fill" x="49.639" y="5.144" width="62" height="25" />
    </g>
    <g class="clipboard-borders">
      <polyline id="clipboard-paper-border" points="131.476,11.44 131.476,162.524 30.753,162.524 30.753,11.44" />
      <rect id="clipboard-clip-border" x="49.639" y="5.144" width="62" height="25" />
      <line id="clipboard-clip-detail" x1="59.081" y1="17.735" x2="103.148" y2="17.735" />
      <line id="clipboard-knob-1" x1="65.376" y1="178.262" x2="71.672" y2="178.262" />
      <line id="clipboard-knob-2" x1="77.967" y1="178.262" x2="84.262" y2="178.262" />
      <line id="clipboard-knob-3" x1="90.557" y1="178.262" x2="96.852" y2="178.262" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Also posted in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/gracelle/pen/RGaKrK).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add `stroke-linecap: square;` to the CSS declarations for the SVG object.

```
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 3% auto;
  padding: 0px 100px;
  stroke-linecap: square;  /* <-- Add this */
}
```

**Example:**

Here's an SVG with two paths (open, not closed). The path drawn with "butt" line endings has a bit missing in the top corner, but the other path (drawn with "square" line endings) doesn't have this issue.

```html
<svg width="250" height="100" viewBox="0 0 250 100">
  <path d="M10 10h80v80h-80v-80" style="stroke:#000; stroke-width:10px; fill:none; stroke-linecap: square;"/>
  <text x="50" y="70" text-anchor="middle">Square</text>
  <path d="M160 10h80v80h-80v-80" style="stroke:#000; stroke-width:10px; fill:none; stroke-linecap: butt;"/>
  <text x="200" y="70" text-anchor="middle">Butt</text>
 </svg>
```

---

<sub>P.S. I like your work, but next time please consider making a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate the problem. That way people won't have to wade through reams of code to discover what's going wrong :-)</sub>

Comment: Thanks so much that worked! 

Ah, I'll do that next time for sure, still getting used to this thing.